# How does player respawn time work?

Tags: pokemon-unite

What are all of the factors that go into your player-controlled character's respawn time, and by how much do they increase your player character's respawn time?

Comment: Based on what I've seen, the only factor is how many un-scored Pokéballs you currently posses. The more you have, the longer the respawn. Although, not sure what other factors there are

Comment: What I've seen it looks more like: the longer you are in the game, the longer it takes to respawn